# Shell/Bash: how to fail on just undefined functions in command-line shell?

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, interrupt

I want to make sure my command-line shell auto fails on just undefined functions.

I do not want my shell scripts to fail on undefined variables since that screws up some external shell scripts that I am sourcing in my .bashrc (Particularly .git-completion.bash starts to misbehave with `set -u` flag)

I also do not want to fail on return code 1 since that would make my shell unusable (grepping for something that doesn't exist in a file would auto exit my shell).

What I do want is hard stop anytime there is a function used that is undefined. Ideally process interrupt like `kill -INT -$$` which would stop the current process right than and there but would not exit the shell, but just exiting the shell would work as well as long as it only works on undefined functions and also works when output of the functions is captured.

What I mean by works with output of functions is captured is just setting `set -u`, `set -e` doesn't even fully get the job done:

```
go1(){
  set -u
  set -e

  iDontExist

  echo "!!! reached operation after undefined !!!"
}
# > go1
# bash: iDontExist: command not found
# Saving session...bash: HISTTIMEFORMAT: unbound variable
```

The above works. However if I capture the output the flags do not catch the undefined error (even though I don't even want to use these flags due to the reasons specified at the beginning of the question)

```
go2(){
  set -u
  set -e
  set -o pipefail

  echo $(iDontExist)

  echo "!!! reached operation after undefined !!!"
}
# > go2
# bash: iDontExist: command not found
#
# !!! reached operation after undefined !!!
```

Is there some other awesome flag that would get the job done?

Comment: `command_not_found_handle() { echo "not found"; }`?

Answer (score 1):

When using `pipefail` and `errorexit` you want to either clear the error status with:

```sh
may_fail_command || true
```

or either deal with the return status in a condition

```sh
declare myvar
if ! myvar="$(may_fail_command)"; then
  printf 'Error assigning myvar because may_fail_command failed code %d\n' $?
fi
```

If you have to source file with possible errors, you can temporarily disable the `errorexit` `nounset` `pipefail` flags.

You should also test the return code of your sourcing

```sh
if ! source may_fail_sourced.sh; then
... handle sourcing errors
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

> if I capture the output

Well, there is a better way to capture it. The `echo $(...)` statement has the exit status of `echo` command, not the `$(...)`, so it will never trigger `set -e`. Do:

```
go2(){
  set -u
  set -e
  set -o pipefail

  str=$(iDontExist)
  echo "$str"

  echo "!!! reached operation after undefined !!!"
}
go2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021): the command line completion (in contrib/) is safer with "`set -u`".

See [commit 76655e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76655e8a28d35c7243fa8f138c90a123aa32357f) (16 Apr 2021) by [Ville Skyttä (`scop`)](https://github.com/scop).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5980e0d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5980e0d44258a6cccf1e5995947d4cba15145924), 30 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`completion`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76655e8a28d35c7243fa8f138c90a123aa32357f): avoid aliased command lookup error in nounset mode
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ville Skyttä</sup>

> Aliased command lookup accesses the `list` variable before it has been set, causing an error in "nounset" mode.
> Initialize to an empty string to avoid that.
>
> ```
> $ git nonexistent-command <Tab>bash: list: unbound variable
> ```